# Find function if known some limit

Tags: analysis, limits, special-functions, gamma-function

I have trouble with the following problem.

Let  $f=f(p)$, $p>1$, $0<f<1$, and $\lim_{p\to\infty}f(p)=1$. 
Find $f(p)$, such that
$$\lim_{p\to\infty}p\left(1-\sqrt{p f(p)}\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{\Gamma(p+\frac 32)}\right)=\frac{3}{20}$$

Comment: How come this question cannot be edited?

Comment: David: do you know a simple equivalent of $\Gamma(p+1)/\Gamma(p+\frac32)$ when $p\to+\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For positive half-integers, the gamma function is given by
$$
\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} + n) = \frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!}\sqrt{\pi},
$$
and so the ratio in question is
$$
\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{\Gamma(p+\frac{3}{2})} = \frac{4^{p+1}p!(p+1)!}{(2p+2)!\sqrt{\pi}}
$$
for integral $p$.  As $p\rightarrow\infty$, this is asymptotic to $p^{-1/2}$, so the limit in the problem becomes
$$
\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}p\left(1-\sqrt{f(p)}\right).
$$
To make this take on a particular finite value $\alpha$, the expression $1-\sqrt{f(p)}$ must be asymptotic to $\alpha/p$, hence $\sqrt{f(p)}$ must be asymptotic to $1-\alpha/p$, hence $f(p)$ must be asymptotic to $1-2\alpha/p$.  Setting $\alpha=3/20$, we have
$$
f(p) = 1-\frac{3}{10p}
$$
as one function that satisfies the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I got that the ratio $\Gamma (p+1)/\Gamma(p+\frac 32)$ is asymptotic to $\sqrt p$, not to $\frac{1}{\sqrt p}$